# scrape replies to a tweet using Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, twitter, jupyter-notebook, scrape

**I've seen some questions and posts on how to scrape tweets of a specific handle, but not on how to do so to get all the replies to a particular tweet using Python via Jupyter Notebook.**

**Example:** I want to scrape and export to Excel all the 340 replies to this public BBC tweet "Microplastics found in fresh Antarctic snow for the first time" (https://twitter.com/BBCWorld/status/1534777385249390593)

I need the following info: Reply date, Reply to (so I only get the replies to BBC, and not to other users in this thread) and the Reply text.

Inspecting the elements of the URL, I see that the reply container's class is named: `css-1dbjc4n`. Likewise:

2. The Reply date's class is: `css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-18u37iz r-1ny4l3l r-1udh08x r-1qhn6m8 r-i023vh r-o7ynqc r-6416eg`
3. The Reply to's class is: `css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-901oao r-14j79pv r-1loqt21 r-1q142lx r-37j5jr r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-3s2u2q r-qvutc0`
4. And the Reply text's class is: `css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0`

I have tried to run the code below, but the list remains empty :(

**Results so far:**

> Empty DataFrame
>
> Columns: [Date of Tweet, Replying to, Tweet]
>
> Index: []

*Can anyone help me, please?
Many thanks! :)*

**Code:**

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path to site-packages in your pc")

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:chromedriver path in your pc")

dates=[] #List to store date of tweet
replies=[] #List to store reply to info
comments=[] #List to store comments
driver.get("https://twitter.com/BBCWorld/status/1534777385249390593")

twts=[]

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for a in soup.findAll('div',href=True, attrs={'class':'css-1dbjc4n'}):
    datetweet=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-18u37iz r-1ny4l3l r-1udh08x r-1qhn6m8 r-i023vh r-o7ynqc r-6416eg'})
    replytweet=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-901oao r-14j79pv r-1loqt21 r-1q142lx r-37j5jr r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-3s2u2q r-qvutc0'})
    commenttweet=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0'})
    dates.append(datetweet.text)
    replies.append(replytweet.text)
    comments.append(commenttweet.text) 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date of Tweet':dates,'Replying to':replies,'Tweet':comments})
df.to_csv('tweets.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
print(df)
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: `twitter` use JavaScript to add elements to page and it may need time for this - so sometimes Selenium may need to `sleep()` to wait for data. And you have to sleep before you get `page_source`

Comment: if you run Jupyter Notebook on local computer then it should work the same way as using directly Python.

Comment: some portals use random names for classes and you may get HTML with different names

Comment: HTML doesn't use `<div href="...">` - so `findAll('div', href=True, ...)` is wrong. remove `href=True`

Comment: Nice points... Some comments and doubts about them:

1) Regarding the sleep/wait, I am running the code in various cells in Jupyter and giving the page a long time to load everything (especially since I am also checking it manually to remove the cookie and login banners. So I don't think this is an issue, agree?

2) Can these random class names be changing each time I run the code? If so, is there any workaround this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two problems:

1. page uses JavaScript to add elements and JavaScript may need time to add all elements to HTML - you may need `time.sleep(...)` before you get `driver.page_source`. OR use [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) in Selenium to wait for some objects (before you get `driver.page_source`).
2. HTML doesn't use `<div href="...">` so your `findAll('div', href=True, ...)` is wrong. You have to remove `href=True`

---

**EDIT:**

I put code which I created but it needs also to scroll page to get more tweets. And later it may need to click `Show more replies` to get even more tweets.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

import pandas as pd
import time

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://twitter.com/BBCWorld/status/1534777385249390593")

time.sleep(10)

# TODO: scroll page to get more tweets
#for _ in range(2):
#    last = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="cellInnerDiv"]')[-1]
#    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", last)
#    time.sleep(3)

all_tweets = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid]//article[@data-testid="tweet"]')

tweets = []

print(len(all_tweets)-1)
for item in all_tweets[1:]: # skip first tweet because it is BBC tweet
    #print('--- item ---')
    #print(item.text)

    print('--- date ---')
    try:
        date = item.find_element(By.XPATH, './/time').text
    except:
        date = '[empty]'
    print(date)
    
    print('--- text ---')
    try:
        text = item.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@data-testid="tweetText"]').text
    except:
        text = '[empty]'
    print(text)

    print('--- replying_to ---')

    try:
        replying_to = item.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[contains(text(), "Replying to")]//a').text
    except:
        replying_to = '[empty]'
    print(replying_to)

    tweets.append([date, replying_to, text])

df = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns=['Date of Tweet', 'Replying to', 'Tweet'])
df.to_csv('tweets.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
print(df)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply!

I removed the `<div href="...">` and run the code again. But then it didn't allow the `.text` attribute when appending. So, I removed it too. Now it gives back a table, but full of "None" entries... 

So this changed something, but not quite there yet!

Date of Tweet Replying to Tweet
0             None        None  None
1             None        None  None
...            ...         ...   ...
1616          None        None  None

Comment: I think `BeautifulSoup` has problem to parse `page_source`. Maybe you should use `driver.find_elements()` (instead of `soup.findall()`), `driver.find_element()` (instead of `soup.find()`)

Comment: Still no luck... I had to change it to `find_elements_by_class_name`, or it wouldn't run. Now I'm getting "[]" instead of "None".

Comment: `for a in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('css-1dbjc4n'):` and `datetweet=a.find_elements_by_class_name('css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-18u37iz r-1ny4l3l r-1udh08x r-1qhn6m8 r-i023vh r-o7ynqc r-6416eg')` for instance

Comment: this page has complex HTML and it may need more complex code - with ie. `XPATH`.

Comment: did you add `sleep`? Without `sleep` you may get empty HTML and you may not find elements.

Comment: Didn't add sleep, but I am running the code blocks far apart with the notebook (they are each in a different cell). Thus, I wait "manually" for the page to load before running the other cell.

Comment: How would you use the XPATH?

Comment: at this moment to get all tweets I test `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid]//article[@data-testid="tweet"]')`. And later I use relative XPATH to get date `item.find_element(By.XPATH, './/time')`, and for text `item.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@data-testid="tweetText"]')`

Comment: Still not it! I used: `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid]//article[@data-testid="tweet"]')`, then `datetweet=a.find_element(By.XPATH, './/time)` and also `commenttweet=a.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@data-testid="tweetText"]')` but got a weird output. Something like:

`<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="1b95fe1f7fac7751afa5aaf8065ad02e",...` for all lines...

Comment: Hey man, I just saw the edited code! Now it really gives back nice results.   Thanks, that is nearly perfect!  :)   However, it skips some tweets (just retrieves like 8 of them); I don't know why. Maybe I need to put some waits or sleeps between tasks; I'll try... Were you able to get all tweets with this code?

Comment: Nope, sleep didn't do the trick, that's not it yet...

Comment: I ran some tests here and removed the comment for the scroll bit, which helped, but now it misses the first tweets before the scroll task... Thus, I am trying to check if I need to give it some more sleep time or if it is something else.

Comment: I didn't test it but some pages remove top items when you scroll down. And they may put them back when you scroll up. Sometimes it need to run loop which scroll only half of screen and get data. Of course there can be also other problem - it may display only main tweets but not comments/responses for these tweets - and this may need to click links to show responses

Comment: Yeah, that's what I think is happening, the top tweets are disappearing. I am trying to scroll back up to see if it helps, but still no luck, I either get the first or the bottom ones. In my case, I just need the main tweets, so this half of the screen may be the way to go. I know it wouldn't be the best for everyone, though, but for me, it would suffice!

Comment: Running the scrapping code before and then after the scroll helped. I then concatenate both arrays. Still, some replies go missing in the process, especially if the page has more replies available for scrapping, like this one: https://twitter.com/BBCWorld/status/1535008151484915735 Still unable to work the "half-page" scroll tough... But looking into it.